# react native firebaseURL not found

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

Upon pushing some data to firebase in react native I get the following error that my firebase database URL is undefined. I am using the android emulator here. Maybe I am missing something I need to push to firebase in my android build gradle file?

I am currently also using firebase auth for this app it it does work perfectly fine but I had to modify the android build gradle. I'm wondering if this could be a similar issue? If so does anyone know what I need to add?

I'm new to react-native sorry :(

[image]

Below is my config and my firebase app initialization

```js
sendNoteToDatabase = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'my api key',
    authDomain: '*********-37824.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://******-37824.firebaseio.com/',
    projectId: '******-23288'
  }

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

  const note = {
    title: "this.state.title",
    who: "this.state.who",
    time: "this.state.time"
  }

  firebase.database().ref('Users/').set(note).then((data) => {
    //success callback
    console.log('data ', data)
  }).catch((error) => {
    //error callback
    console.log('error ', error)
  })
}
```

I have checked the URL and I am using a realtime database. I'm not sure if this is an issue with my code structure or a problem with android?

Comment: It looks like something in your app is trying to use the database before it's initialized. The stack trace in the error will tell you exactly where that is coming from.

Comment: thank you! this helped me realize that I needed to initialize the app using a hook

Answer (score 1):

using Franks Advice I was able to solve it by initializing the firebase app using the componentDidMount hook

```
componentDidMount(){
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
  }
```